Function erlang:error/1 is undefined in ?assert
I'm playing around with Erlang's EUnit for the first time:
-ifdef(TEST).
-include_lib("eunit/include/eunit.hrl").
simple_test() -> ?assert(1 + 2 =:= 3).
-endif.

It works just as expected when I run it with rebar3 eunit, but elp in neovim reports an error Function 'erlang:error/1' is undefined in the line with ?assert. I think, it's something in the expanded macro. Why does it happen, and how can I get rid of it?
Update: after further investigation, it seems that elp doesn't find the erlang module.
